# Quemu Network How to?

Tags: linux, networking, gentoo

Hi I'm Really new to quemu well I have try many times but here it's exactly where i get problem i do

`qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom install-x86-minimal-20211220T170558Z.iso -cpu host -enable-kvm -m 2048 -smp 2 -drive file=asterisk_gentoo.qcow2,format=qcow2`

and inside of the quemu machine I try get up the network since it's a device called enps3 and try to add as one more device on my network sadly unsuccessfully

I have read some obviously not enough but it's because it's really hard to understand and examples apply for an specific configuration then I need to create a devices net-dev but witch one ?

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -netdev help
Available netdev backend types:
socket
hubport
tap
user
l2tpv3
bridge
vhost-user
vhost-vdpa
```

I'm using Gentoo and at the moment only want to get access to internet from the quemu machine I not that good understanding technicalities.

definitely I could understand if some one tell me do this and i will read why, please ! and thank you all for your time

Comment: Has a bridge been raised on your host?

Comment: Full disclosure, it's my blog, but these two links will help you out: https://krackout.wordpress.com/2020/03/08/network-bridges-and-tun-tap-interfaces-in-linux/ and https://krackout.wordpress.com/2019/10/18/qemu-kvm-command-line/

Comment: Hi nezabudka and Krackout this is the kaind of problem I get to read diferents tutorials I try to do `ip link add Gefyra0 type bridge
Error: Unknown device type.` ????

Comment: I'm asking that on Gentoo Forums it look it's something whit the kernel !

Comment: Have you upgraded the kernel but not rebooted the gentoo host machine? It's a scenario where you'd get that kind of error.

Comment: Yes well kinda i forgot to mount /boot before recompile the kernel but it's done, Krackout i have a question in `ip tuntap add QemuTap0 mode tap user A_Username` the A_Username ? i get `invalid user "A_Username"` even if i place my user name